# Numbers in Dash appear only after pressing Super+<Number>

Tags: shortcut-keys, gui, unity-dash, 17.10

I recently installed Ubuntu 17.10 on my laptop, and I'm irritated by the behavior regarding the <kbd>Super</kbd> + <kbd>*Number*</kbd>  shortcut to open an application in the dash: The numbers on the icons in the dash are shown only after pressing a number. (Also, holding the Super key does not make the dash appear (I configured the dash to automatically hide when a window overlaps it). This isn't that big of a deal, as I can just release Super in order to display the application overview.)

I could, of course, try and remember which number was which app, or count through the icons, to figure out which number to press. Still, this is somewhat unsatisfying and I can't imagine that this behavior was intended this way.

Is there anything we can do about it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found a solution: You can press <kbd>Super</kbd> + <kbd>Q</kbd> to make the dash appear with enumerated icons for about two seconds. I figured this out by playing around with key combinations. It is not listed in the system preferences, though.

So have fun now

Cheers

Comment: This is super annoying. And it looks like competing for the application overlay focus.